# JavaFX: Is it a good idea to save threads in a collection? and how to do that?

Tags: multithreading, javafx, collections, runnable

I have several buttons, each of them, when pressed, creates a Thread. 
I want that if pressed again, a button stops its process.

Would it be a good idea to store them in a structure like a collection? or is it stupid?

Thanks

Comment: You wouldn't normally store the actual `Thread` reference. Instead, you'd store the [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) (obtained by submitting the task to an `ExecutorService`) or the more JavaFX specific [`Worker`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html) reference. When you press the `Button` again you'd get the correct reference and call the corresponding `cancel` method. _Note: Cancelling background tasks requires cooperation from the developer._

Comment: To add to/clarify what Slaw said - creating `Thread`s haphazardly is usually not a good idea, as you may starve the system of resources - threads aren't free, and can and should be reused. Using an `ExecutorService` will help you make sure you're not creating too much threads and you are reusing threads when possible.